# Alternate solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is my system of DEs.
$$
\begin{align} 
 & \frac {dx} {dt}=2(x-y) \\
 & \frac {dy} {dt}= y-x  
\end{align}
$$

Upon solving this, I get the following:
$$X=C_1+C_2 \begin{pmatrix}-2 \\1 \end{pmatrix}e^{3t}$$

Given that my two eigenvectors are: $K_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$   and $K_2=\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$ with roots $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=3$. Because I do not have the solution to this, I plugged in to WolframAlpha and get something completely different and I'm not sure why. My question, is it possible to have an equivalent answer written differently when solving systems of DEs?

**Solution at Wolfram: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx%2Fdt%3D2x-2y%2Cdy%2Fdt%3Dy-x

Comment: Solving the system, to me and to Alpha, is to find an explicit expression for $(x(t),y(t))$, and **not** to express $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Also, you cannot have an exponential relationship between $y$ and $x$ because solving those simultaneously by observing that $\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{dt} \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{2}$ would quickly give you $y = -\frac{1}{2}x + c$. Going from this to express each equation in terms of the single (relevant) variable and then solving them by separation would give you the same answer as Wolfram.

Comment: @Deepak
My problem with this is that what you're telling me doesn't match how the book solves these equations. For example:

$$
\begin{align} 
 & \frac {dx} {dt}=2x+3y \\
 & \frac {dy} {dt}=2x+y
\end{align}
$$ 

This answer is give in the form of: $$X=c_1\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-1  \end{pmatrix}e^{-t} +c_2 \begin{pmatrix}3 \\2 \end{pmatrix}e^{4t}$$
 which of course doesn't correspond to how Alpha solves it.

Answer (score 5):

### HINT

We have:
$$
\begin{align} 
 & \frac {dx} {dt}=2(x-y) \tag{1} \\
 & \frac {dy} {dt}= y-x  \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Now, $ (2) / (1) $ would give you:

$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = - \dfrac{1}{2} $$
or, $$ y = -\dfrac{x}{2} + C_1 $$

Furthermore, put this $ y(x) $ in equation $ (1) $ and solve for $ x(t) $.

---

The equation would be:

$$ \dfrac{dx}{dt} = 2x + x - C_1 = 3x - C_1$$